# How to count git commit numbers which contains filename (*_test.cpp)?

Tags: bash, git

`git log --grep "xxx"` only search commit log while `git log -- *_test.cpp` only shows commit just contains *_test.cpp.

Is there a way to show commits which contains filename (*_test.cpp)? I'd like to count both commit1, commit2 and commit3 case.

```
commit1: 
    /path_a/file_a.cpp; 
    /path_a/file_b.cpp; 
    /path_b/file_a_test.cpp; 

commit2: /path_c/file_b_test.cpp

commit3: /path_d/file_d_test.cpp
    /path_e/file_e_test.cpp
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title says count, your question body says show.

Count:

```
git rev-list --count @ -- \*_test.cpp
```

list:

```
git rev-list @ -- \*_test.cpp
```

show:

```
git log @ -- \*_test.cpp
```

and I'd recommend adding either `--no-merges` or `--first-parent` to avoid redundantly listing every merge that forwarded changes along with the commit that made it.

---

> `git log -- *_test.cpp` only shows commit just contains `*_test.cpp`

That's not how `git log` works for me, and its not how it's documented to work. Check your evidence, I think you're misunderstanding whatever led you to say that, for instance, in my git repo:

```
$ git log -10  --pretty=format:  --name-only --no-merges @ -- \*-*.c
refs/files-backend.c

builtin/cat-file.c

builtin/cat-file.c

fmt-merge-msg.c

t/helper/test-drop-caches.c

stable-qsort.c

builtin/update-index.c
read-cache.c

builtin/receive-pack.c

builtin/cat-file.c
builtin/rev-list.c

ref-filter.c
$
```

but adding the `--full-diff` option gives a much longer list of files touched by those commits.

Comment: I guess I didn't make my problem clear. Let me use an example. e.g. commit1: /path_a/file_a.cpp; /path_b/file_a_test.cpp; commit 2: /path_c/file_b_test.cpp;  right now git log '*_test.cpp' or git log '**/*_test.cpp' will only show commit 2. It does't include commit1. I'd like to count both of them. Is there a way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: The syntax you're saying does not work does not match the syntax I'm showing, which does work. Read the last line of my answer: at least several of those commits touched many more files than just what's shown.

Comment: I tried `git log --stat @ -- \*_test.cpp` and in my test repo, it won't show commit1 case and only show commit2 cases.

Comment: I'm showing the evidence I'm looking at with c&p's from my terminal buffer and using examples you can try for yourself, that's the Git history and the patterns I'm using are exact analogs for what you say doesn't work for you. They work for me. What version of git are you using? Show the evidence you're looking at.

Comment: I tried in two different env: linux env: `git version 2.17.1`, mac env: 'git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)' both of them produced same results. I guess I might miss something. Thanks.

Comment: I just built and installed 2.17.1 on my linux box and ran it with the `\*-*.c` pattern, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the `**` wildcard will get you what you want:

```
git log '**/*_test.cpp'
```

`**` matches any number of directories. For more details, see [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-glob).

Comment: I tried `git log --stat '**/*_test.cpp'` in my linux env: (git version 2.17.1) it only shows commit2 and commit3 cases.